# How can I efficiently export multiple classes in ES6 JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

In my ES6 Node.js application, I have a file of classes that I'm exporting:

```
class Class1 {...}
class Class2 {...}

module.exports = {
    Class1, Class2
}
```

If one day I make Class3, I don't want to have to remember to add it to the exports list. What I'd like is something like:

```
module.exports = {
    class Class1 {...},
    class Class2 {...}
}
```

Is there any syntax that accomplishes this?

Comment: You could write `module.exports = { Class1: class {…}, Class2: class {…}};`, but why not just use ES6 modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add the export at the same time you define the class:

```
module.exports.Class1 = class Class1 {...};
module.exports.Class2 = class Class2 {...};
```

It's not much better but may be easier to remember.

Comment: Still have to write the class name twice, but this way I can't forget. Good enough

Comment: Outside of Node.js, in standard ES6 JavaScript, you could just say `export class Class1 {...}` and you wouldn't have to write the class name twice.

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an ES6 solution: just add `export` before declaring your class :)

```js
export class Foo() {

}

export class Bar() {

}

export class Baz() {

}
```

`module.exports` works fine but is CommonJs, not ES6!

In another file you can import them with the following statements:

```
import * as MyClasses from './path/classes.js'

const foo = new MyClasses.Foo()
```

or

```
import { Foo, Bar, Baz } from './path/classes.js'

const foo = new Foo()
```

Comment: I don't think your distinction is correct. Classes are ES6 and CommonJS + classes still counts as ES6. The question doesn't reference ES module syntax, so presumably the mention if ES6 is in reference to other common ES6 features, not specifically ES module syntax. Using ES module syntax is certainly fine in some cases, but the question also never mentions Babel, just standard Node.